# Grid search CV - TypeError: Singleton array array(None, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to perform grid search CV and I am getting the following error:

TypeError: Singleton array array(None, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.

Not sure what is causing this - any help on the error would be much appreciated.

Code is as follows:

```
# text pipeline
text_steps = [('feature extractor', SelectColumnsTransfomer(text_features)),
              ('tf-idf', Tfidf),
              ('classifier', MLPclf)]

# define steps
pl_text = Pipeline(text_steps)

parameters = {
    'tf-idf__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    'tf-idf__max_features': (5000, 10000, 50000),
    'tf-idf__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    'classifier__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001, 1e-05),
    'classifier__hidden_layer_sizes': ((1, 5), (1, 5, 10))
}

# find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
# classifier
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pl_text, parameters, verbose=1, refit=True)
grid_search.fit(X_train)
```

SelectColumnsTransfer class:

```
class SelectColumnsTransfomer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """ A DataFrame transformer that provides column selection

Allows to select columns by name from pandas dataframes in scikit-learn
pipelines.

Parameters
----------
columns : list of str, names of the dataframe columns to select
    Default: []

"""

def __init__(self, columns=[]):
    self.columns = columns

def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
    """ Selects columns of a DataFrame

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : pandas DataFrame

    Returns
    ----------

    trans : pandas DataFrame
        contains selected columns of X
    """
    trans = X[self.columns].copy()
    return trans

def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    """ Do nothing function

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : pandas DataFrame
    y : default None


    Returns
    ----------
    self
    """
    return self
```

Dataframe has following features:

Area   gender   age   text

Comment: what are text_features and how is SelectColumnsTransfer defined -- from the base, or custom-coded? which line has the error? my guess is the structure of X_train? print the head of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Skrubber. I've added the custom class and a snippet from the dataframe head columns. I think you might be right, just can't figure out where. I had some issues getting sklearn to select a column to transform in the pipeline (hence the custom class to do this).

Comment: Please print the type and shape of `trans` in the transform function.